# ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS, LdapErr: DSID-0C09128B "TLS or SSL already in effect"

Tags: php, ldap

I am trying to do LDAP authenticate with certificate in AWS Beanstalk and EC2 (PHP 8.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.4).

.pem certificate is in /etc/openldap/certs

My PHP Code as follows :

```php
$ldaprdn  = 'username@dc1.dc2';
$ldappass = 'password';

$ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://ldaps.hostname.com:636")
        or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if ($ldapconn) {
    $ldapbind = @ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldaprdn, $ldappass);
    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "LDAP bind successful...\n";
    } else {
        echo "LDAP bind failed...\n";
    }
}

echo "ldap_error: " . ldap_error($ldapconn);
ldap_get_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err);
echo "ldap_get_option: $err";
```

I get the following warning:

Warning: ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Operations error in /var/app/current/auth1.php on line 26 ldap_error: Operations errorldap_get_option: 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C09128B, comment: TLS or SSL already in effect, data 0, v3839 Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Operations error in /var/app/current/auth1.php on line 48 Error - Operations error

Comment: Please also mark the line on which this error happens in your code sample.

Comment: line 26 has         echo "LDAP bind successful...\n";
I don't have a line 48 in my file

Comment: Remove (or comment out) lines/code blocks from the end of your file until you identify the line that triggers the error.

Comment: I guess it is the ldapconn and ldapbind that is generating the error.